# Join two tables juxtaposing columns with same name sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two sqlite3 tables with same column names and I want to compare them. To do that, I need to join the tables and juxtapose the columns with same name.
The tables share an identical column which I want to put as the first column.

Let's imagine I have table t1 and table t2

Table t1:

```
SharedColumn | Height | Weight
        A    |   2    |   70
        B    |   10   |   100
```

Table t2:

```
SharedColumn | Height | Weight
        A    |   5    |   25
        B    |   32   |   30
```

What I want get as a result of my query is :

```
SharedColumn | Height_1 | Height_2 | Weight_1 | Weight_2
        A     |    2     |     5    |    70    |    25    
        B     |    10    |     32   |    100   |    30
```

In my real case i have a lot of columns so I would like to avoid writing each column name twice to specify the order.

Renaming the columns is not my main concern, what interests me the most is the juxtaposition of columns with same name.

Comment: what is your query you need to execute and join tables?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to write the query, that's my problem. I am looking for a query that could merge my two tables as described in the little example I gave with t1 and t2 tables.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that directly in SQL especially because you also want to rename the columns to identify their source, you'll have to use dynamic SQL and honestly? Don't! .

Simply write the columns names, most SQL tools provide a way to generate the select, just copy them and place them in the correct places :

```
SELECT t1.sharedColumn,t1.height as height_1,t2.height as height_2 ...
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON(t1.sharedColumn = t2.sharedColumn)+
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I thought about this query structure too. Writing each column name in the SELECT is indeed an option.
However, I would prefer not to have to write them one by one.
How about getting the same result table structure but without renaming the columns ? Because you seem to say the renaming is the main problem

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query to get the desired result!!

```
SELECT t1.Height AS Height_1, t1.Weight AS Weight_1, t1.sharedColumn AS SharedColumn
   t2.Height AS Height_2, t2.Weight AS Weight_2
   FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
   ON t1.sharedColumn = t2.sharedColumn
   ORDER By t1.sharedColumn ASC
```

After that, you can fetch the result by following lines:

```
$result['SharedColumn'];
$result['Height_1'];
$result['Height_2'];
$result['Weight_1'];
$result['Weight_1'];
```